# Change the accessed list every iteration of a loop

Tags: python, arrays, list

If I have the code:

```
while d<20:
    num = row1[a]*row1[b]*row1[c]*row1[d]
    if num > largest:
        largest = num
    a+=1
    b+=1
    c+=1
    d+=1
```

and I want it to be (after it iterates):

```
while d<20:
    num = row2[a]*row2[b]*row2[c]*row2[d]
    if num > largest:
        largest = num
    a+=1
    b+=1
    c+=1
    d+=1
```

How can I do that.
For reference, rowx are lists and a,b,c, and d are selecting data points.

To sum it up, I want to search a different list after each iteration, is that possible?

*edit* I forgot to mention that its important I don't have a different loop for each row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the lists in a list

```
rows = [row1, row2]  # or however many
for row in rows:
    # setup
    while d < 20:
         # your code but with row1 replaced with row
```

Comment: you do not have to assume a `row3`

Comment: It works regardless up to rowN, but this works great, thanks!

Comment: @Zanolon if you have an unspecified number of `rowN`, it's best you have the `rows` set up as a `list` of `list` so it's expandable.  e.g. `rows = [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]...]` and then reference `for row in rows`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible by iterating over a list of those rows.

```
list_of_rows = [row1, row2] # etc.
for row in list_of_rows:
    while d<20:
        num = row[a]*row[b]*row[c]*row[d]
        if num > largest:
            largest = num
        a+=1
        b+=1
        c+=1
        d+=1
```